# Class exists but jquery errors: TypeError $(...) is null

Tags: jquery, typeerror

At the bottom of the website http://yn1[dot]nl there is a button called "Inloggen". When you click on it a div called "userdata" should show up. For some mysterious reason nothing happens.

Firebug says:

```
TypeError: $(...) is null
Line: 46
```

That line includes:

```
$(".userdata").toggle("4000", function() { });
```

What is wrong about that? The `div` exists and has the class name "userdata".

Comment: The [`.toggle()`](http://jsapi.info/jquery/1.8.3/jQuery.fn.toggle) won't animate for 4 seconds as the first parameter is either a `Number` which represents the animation time in milliseconds or one of the predefined properties in `jQuery.fx.speeds = { slow: 600, fast: 200, _default: 400 }`

Comment: even just toggle() isn't working

Answer (score 1):

The error message is clear: `$(...)` returns `null`. That means the `$` global variable cannot be equal to `jQuery`, because `jQuery` would never return `null` (regardless of whether the div in question exists or not).

Indeed, your code includes a no-conflict script that calls [`jQuery.noConflict`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/), which relinquishes control of the `$` variable.

Solution: either remove the no-conflict script (which might break other things, I have no idea) or else write `jQuery` instead of `$`.

Comment: I changed $(document) in jQuery(document). But no result.
After I changed $document to just $, still no div is showing up.

Comment: @YolkNet: There is no `$(document)` in your question, so I don't know what you are talking about. You would have to change `$` to `jQuery` *everywhere* (better: everywhere where it refers to jQuery).

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant I now have this:
jQuery.ready(function() {

 $(".inloggen").click(function() {
  $(".userdata").toggle();
 });
});

Comment: @YolkNet: **Everywhere**.

Comment: Indeed it was a conflict. I solved it with this code:

$(document).ready(function() {
 var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
 
 // Frontend inloggen
 $(".inloggen").click(function() {
  $(".userdata").toggle(800);
 });
});