# How to click on a <span> using javascript. <span> has no class or id

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to click on a `<span>` on page element load but my span has no class or ID.
The span is

```
<div class="block-title">
<strong><span>Refine By</span></strong>
</div>
```

I want something like

```
 $('.block-title > span').click();
```

But this returns error

> TypeError: $(...) is null

Comment: You want to attach a click event to it?

Comment: `$('.block-title > span').click(function() { });`

Comment: I want some thing like this $('.block-title > span').click();
But this returns error 
TypeError: $(...) is null

Comment: You mean $('.block-title span').click(); You need to adjust your selector first

Comment: @  Erwin this gives error in console TypeError: $(...) is null

Comment: how about `$('.block-title').find('span').click()` ?

Comment: You want to trigger an event, right? Not attach a listener?

Comment: Are you even sure that jQuery is included and loaded before your script?

Answer (score 9):

If you want to trigger a click on the element, you can do it like this:

```
var span= document.querySelector(".block-title span");
var click= new Event('click');
span.dispatchEvent(click);
```

**[Complete Vanilla JS Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jacobgray/fxhv7vc7/)**

Or, if you want the jQuery(yuck) version:

```
//Creates and dispatches a click event
$('.block-title span').trigger('click');
```

**[Complete jQuery Version](http://jsfiddle.net/jacobgray/p9gwuarz/)**

---

**Older answer**

Using pure javascript, you can set the `onclick` of an element to a function:

```
document.querySelector(".block-title span").onclick = fn;
// or like document.querySelector(".block-title span").onclick = function(){};
```

Or, if you want to use an event listener:

```
var span = document.querySelector(".block-title span");
span.attachEvent('onclick', fn);
span.addEventListener('click', fn, false);
```

Or, if you want to use jQuery(yuck):

```
$('.block-title span').click(function() { });
```

Comment: I want some thing like this $('.block-title > span').click();
But this returns error 
TypeError: $(...) is null

Comment: That's jQuery, my answer just uses Vanilla JS

Comment: And that is null, your selector is messed up.

Comment: @SheikhSiddiquee `span` is not a direct child of `.block-title`

Comment: @JacobGray Pure JS for the win and +1 for the yuck =]

Comment: I dont want onclick, i want to trigger a click.

Comment: So remove the function:  `$('.block-title span').click();`

Comment: i am trying document.getElementsByClassName("block-title").click(); gives me error .click(); is not a function . any idea?

Comment: @SheikhSiddiquee that won't work. One, `getElementsByClassName` returns a HTMLCollection, which, like an array, needs to be looped through. Two, there is no function `click()`, that is jquery.

Comment: I believe you could do `document.getElementsByClassName("block-title")[0].click()` - Click should be available on [any html element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click)

Comment: @mplungjan I didn't even know about that... It looks like `click()` only works on `inputs`, or at least that is what I got from reading it

Answer (score 1):

Use .trigger(type) from the jQuery API

```
$('.block-title span').trigger('click');
```

http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: @ Simon, I get TypeError: $(...) is null  in console

Comment: Probably because the element doesn't exist then

Comment: element is exixt 110%. I have copied the code from the source

Comment: Type $ in the console and see what you get, then type $('.block-title') and so on... If you get an error on $, you haven't included jquery

Comment: i am trying document.getElementsByClassName("block-title").click(); gives me error .click(); is not a function . any idea?

Answer (score 1):

If you get the following error then it means there is some other issue with your javascript:

> TypeError: $(...) is null

I would suggest doing some research. I copied that into Google and got:

1. [TypeError: $(...) is null error in firebug but code works on jsFiddle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14203125/typeerror-is-null-error-in-firebug-but-code-works-on-jsfiddle)
2. ["TypeError: $(...) is null" What's Going On?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16171681/typeerror-is-null-whats-going-on)
3. [Class exists but jquery errors: TypeError $(...) is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19978428/class-exists-but-jquery-errors-typeerror-is-null)